# How to use "addEventListener Change" to change value in textarea?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I want to create a textarea, when an option is selected then the value in the textarea is a value of the selected option.

I tried using code like this but it doesn't work as I expected.

```
selectVal.addEventListener('change', updateTextareaContent);
```

Full code look like this

```js
let custname = document.getElementById('custname');
let invoicenum = document.getElementById('invoicenum');

let valTextarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
function updateTextareaContent(){
valTextarea.value=`Name: ${custname.value||''}
Invoice: ${invoicenum.value||''}
Color Selected: ${selectVal.value||''}
`;
}

custname.addEventListener('keydown', updateTextareaContent);
invoicenum.addEventListener('keydown', updateTextareaContent);
custname.addEventListener('keyup', updateTextareaContent);
invoicenum.addEventListener('keyup', updateTextareaContent);

selectVal.addEventListener('change', updateTextareaContent);

function myFunction(e) {
    document.getElementById("selectVal").value = e.target.value
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="my-3">
    <input id="custname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name">
  </div>
  
  <div class="mb-3">
    <input id="invoicenum" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Invoice Num">
  </div>

<select class="form-select" onchange="myFunction(event)">
    <option disabled selected>Choose Database Type</option>
    <option value="Green color">green</option>
    <option value="Red color">red</option>
    <option value="Orange color">orange</option>
    <option value="Black color">black</option>
</select>

  <div class="mt-3">
    <input id="selectVal" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="colors" readonly>
  </div>

  <div class="my-3">
    <label>Result textarea</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" rows="4">
Name:
Invoice:
Color Selected:
    </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Exactly what I expected it to look like in this picture:
[image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbbib.png)

I hope someone is willing to help solve it :)
Thanks

Comment: Two things off the top of my head: (1) you never defined `selectVal` in the code snippet you posted, and (2) does the code run _after_ the HTML is parsed? If it is, e.g., embedded in `<head>`, `getElementById` won’t find an element and return `null`.

Comment: Hi @Boldewyn Exactly what I expected it to look like in this picture >> https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbbib.png

Comment: your 'selectVal' control is readonly why you want to change  addEventListener to that control? Instead you can do this . function myFunction(e) {
    document.getElementById("selectVal").value = e.target.value;updateTextareaContent();
}

Comment: Hi @Sund'er Thanks for the comments, can you help provide an example of writing the code?
I get "readonly" it has absolutely no effect, even if I remove "readonly" it's still the same not work.

Comment: INPUT change event only fires when the user types into the input and then loses focus. just change these lines in your code it will work as you expected . selectVal.addEventListener('blur', updateTextareaContent);

function myFunction(e) {   
     
     document.getElementById("selectVal").value = e.target.value;
     document.getElementById("selectVal").selectionEnd = 0;
     document.getElementById("selectVal").focus();
     valTextarea.focus();
}

Comment: Thanks, I tried the simple way you taught and it worked really well
`function myFunction(e) { document.getElementById("selectVal").value = e.target.value;updateTextareaContent(); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that there is no event handler for the `select` element that will call `updateTextareaContent`. There is one that will update `selectVal`, but nothing else will happen.

Listen to the `input` event, as that will trigger for any user action that will change the value (like click, keyboard, context menu, drag/drop, ...etc).

Instead of setting up a handler for each form control, just set it up on the level of the container element itself: the `input` event will bubble up to the container, no matter which control it initially came from, and so you'll have a "catch all".

Use explicit variable declarations -- not relying on the fact that there will be globals created for the `id` attributes in the HTML document. Give the color selector an id, so you can also reference it with a variable.

```js
let custname = document.getElementById('custname');
let invoicenum = document.getElementById('invoicenum');
let valTextarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
// add these:
let selectVal = document.getElementById('selectVal'); 
let container = document.querySelector(".container");
let selector = document.getElementById("colorselector");

function updateForm(){
    // Move the other update here (no more "myFunction")
    selectVal.value = selector.value
    // 
    valTextarea.value=`Name: ${custname.value||''}
Invoice: ${invoicenum.value||''}
Color Selected: ${selectVal.value||''}`;
}

container.addEventListener("input", updateForm);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="my-3">
    <input id="custname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name">
  </div>
  
  <div class="mb-3">
    <input id="invoicenum" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Invoice Num">
  </div>

  <select class="form-select" id="colorselector"> <!-- Remove onchange, give id -->
    <option disabled selected>Choose Database Type</option>
    <option value="Green color">green</option>
    <option value="Red color">red</option>
    <option value="Orange color">orange</option>
    <option value="Black color">black</option>
  </select>

  <div class="mt-3">
    <input id="selectVal" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="colors" readonly>
  </div>

  <div class="my-3">
    <label>Result textarea</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" rows="4">
Name:
Invoice:
Color Selected:
    </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Summary of all the changes:

- HTML: remove `onclick` attribute, add `id` attribute for the collor selector
- Variables: create variables for *all* elements you need to reference
- Functions: rename function to `update`, and merge the functionality of `myFunction` into it, removing `myFunction`. Also make it independent on the event object and instead reference the elements via variable name.
- Events: replace all calls to `addEventListener` by one that listens on the container element for `input` events.

Comment: Hi @trincot Thanks for your answer, you saved my time. this is as I expected, can you give a little explanation on which parts were changed?

Comment: I added a list of changes at the end of the answer. I thought the beginning of the answer already gave explanations. What exactly needs more clarification?

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful, a few additional questions what if this doesn't have a container class?

Comment: Then there is always the body element which can act as container.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **input** event.

```js
 selectVal.addEventListener('input', updateTextareaContent);
```

Change event be active when you lose focus.

Comment: Hi @quin I've tried using "input" but it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, I haven't to code it. And I'm glad that you already get the answer you want.